# Why UUID is called a 128-bit number even though it contains letters?

Tags: uuid

Does it mean that the usual format of 32 hex characters has the same number of combinations as a 128-bit number? I realize this is a basic question, but couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: In hexadecimal, `A` is a number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hexadecimal digit has 16 (2<sup>4</sup>) possible values, so each can represent exactly 4 bits.

Put 32 of them together, and they can represent 32 × 4 = 128 bits.

Answer (score 1):

(Writing a question got me thinking and lead to further googling)
Yes. You get 32 hexadecimal *numbers*, each one may represent one of 16 symbols: 0-9 and A-F. In binary system you can get 16 combinations by using 4-bit binary number, so e.g. F (hex number) is the same as 1111 (binary number). From there 32 * 4bit = 128bit.

Comment: This isn't exactly true, though, because not any arbitrary 128-bit number is a valid UUID. Some bits are used to describe the UUID version and some bits describe the variant. So, with some of the 128 bits having a [special meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format), _for a given version and variant_ you would have a less-than-128-bit identifier. Really your question is not specific to UUIDs but numbers in general: hexadecimal "contains letters" because that's what it uses to _represent_ numbers; binary or, say, octal don't because their base doesn't need them.